# Bootstrap grid that fills viewport without overflow

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 to try to come up with what I think is a really simple layout. I want to show an MxN grid of cells. Each cell being the same size. I want this to fill the entire viewport without scrollbars in either direction. Scrollbars are where I'm getting stuck.

I've tried different combinations of height and max-height on the various divs. This was helpful on the container div to keep it from growing too tall, but the rows end up overflowing vertically. What I really want is for everything to shrink down to where there are no scrollbars, even if it means the columns get narrower. Ideally I'd like to use bootstrap, but that's not necessarily a requirement.

The below snippet is where I'm at. It seems to be about 20% taller than the viewport.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row p-0">
    <div class="col p-0 border">
      <span class="ratio ratio-16x9 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        Cell
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0 border">
      <span class="ratio ratio-16x9 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        Cell
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row p-0">
    <div class="col p-0 border">
      <span class="ratio ratio-16x9 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        Cell
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0 border">
      <span class="ratio ratio-16x9 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        Cell
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit 1:**

It appears the issue is with aspect-ratio. It seems to want to fill the width even at the expense of growing the height larger than the cell.

Here's an updated example without the ratios. It renders and responds correctly:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100 mh-100 vh-100 flex-column">
  <div class="row p-0 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col p-0 border d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div>
        Cell
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0 border d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div>
        Cell
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row p-0 flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col p-0 border d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div>
        Cell
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0 border d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <div>
        Cell
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The ultimate goal would be to get the cell divs to always be at a 16/9 aspect ratio without growing larger than the parent div as well as being centered both horizontally and vertically in the parent. I suppose in other words, the cell divs need to grow until either the height or width reaches the parent and stop there. Instead, it seems to grow until width reaches the parent width, even if the height is taller than the parent.

Also, I should clarify the number of rows/columns is dynamic so that might affect how a solution would work as I wouldn't be able to hard-code any sizing relative to number of rows and columns.

If it helps, the end goal is to have a grid of videos that have to be shown on one screen without scrolling.

**Edit 2:**

Just for more clarification, here's what I'm expecting in the solution:

1. No scrollbars anywhere. This is likely to be used in situations where the user can't be expected to scroll.
2. Needs to work regardless of how many rows/columns I have in the layout, though it's reasonable to assume there will be a small enough number of cells that the content is still easily visible.
3. Content of each cell will be videos.
4. All videos need to have the same aspect ratio.
5. Since it's unlikely that the cell dimensions are going to match video aspect ratio, the video needs to be centered horizontally and vertically in the cell.
6. User may be resizing the browser, so resizing needs to happen accordingly.
7. Ideally I'd prefer to stick with bootstrap or straight up css, but will consider other options if this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if the following is what you are after, but have a look. Note that it uses the CSS4 property `aspect-ratio`, read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio and see browser support here https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio

I didn't use bootstrap for a long time now, so not too familiar with it's classes anymore ;), but I think if you really want to use it, you can easily find the matching classes within the bootstrap framework to replicate the little CSS this implementation needs (look at utility classes mainly)

PS: Ignore the JS code, it's just for demonstration purposes so you can dynamically add or remove items from the grid and see how it reacts.

```js
    function addItem(e) {
        document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(document.querySelector('.col:first-of-type').cloneNode(true));
    }

    function removeItem(e) {
        e.remove();
    }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 12px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20%, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr));
    width: 100%; height: 100vh;
}
.col {
    background: #444;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
}
.col > * {
    background: #999;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    object-fit: contain;
    max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col" onclick="removeItem(this)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x405?text=16:9" alt="Thumbnail" title="Click me and i will disappear!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" onclick="removeItem(this)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x405?text=16:9" alt="Thumbnail" title="Click me and i will disappear!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" onclick="removeItem(this)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x405?text=16:9" alt="Thumbnail" title="Click me and i will disappear!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" onclick="removeItem(this)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x405?text=16:9" alt="Thumbnail" title="Click me and i will disappear!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" onclick="removeItem(this)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x405?text=16:9" alt="Thumbnail" title="Click me and i will disappear!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" onclick="removeItem(this)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x405?text=16:9" alt="Thumbnail" title="Click me and i will disappear!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" onclick="removeItem(this)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x405?text=16:9" alt="Thumbnail" title="Click me and i will disappear!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" onclick="removeItem(this)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x405?text=16:9" alt="Thumbnail" title="Click me and i will disappear!" />
    </div>
    <div class="col" onclick="removeItem(this)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x405?text=16:9" alt="Thumbnail" title="Click me and i will disappear!" />
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="addItem(this)" style="background: #be0000; color: white; border: 0; border-radius: 3px; padding: 8px 24px; position: fixed; top: 12px; left: 12px;">Add item</button>

<style>

</style>

<script>

</script>
```

Comment: I might have been too hasty to say it works. It worked when running the code snippet from stackoverflow. However, something about my site is causing it to still overflow. Maybe bootstrap is messing it up. At least it gives me a path to go down.

Comment: you could post a jsbin or something with the full setup and i can have a look? but yeah, i simply constrained the container by full viewport height, so if you have any other elements outside of that container, then you would have to account for that (like headers/footers etc.)

Comment: I think I got it maybe figured out. If I have more problems, I'll try to post an example. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to see where my next problem is. The number of columns is going to be dynamic. If I understand your example well enough, it's going to wrap at 4 columns right? I need to be able to change that on the fly. Here's an example using bootstrap/angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ykn9dn?file=src/app/grid/grid.component.html. You can change the rows and cols attributes in app.component.html to see what I mean.

Comment: You could adjust that dynamically via css by setting the `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20%, 1fr));` to something else, e.g. other than 20%

Comment: Is there a formula to use to figure out the right percentage? Based on your example, I thought it was 100 / (number of columns + 1), but I'm getting some weird layout depending on whether I round up or down. For instance, for 2 columns, 34% gives me the expected 2 columns, but there's lots of padding (both horizontal and vertical) around the image. 33% looks a lot better padding wise, but gives me 3 columns.

Comment: I also attempted to use grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr)) in conjunction with grid-auto-flow: column, but it kept wanting to give me 1 column.

Comment: hm, maybe this can help somehow? https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-grid-layout-minmax/

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'm getting closer. I'm now dynamically generating grid-template-columns with 1fr for however many columns I want. And I've found out the extra padding is being caused by one of two things. object-fit: contain causes it.  If I switch to object-fit: fill, and remove align-content: center it renders good for narrow/tall grids. But if it's a wide/short grid, it seems to stretch the height to fill the grid cell. Putting align-content: center back in fixes that, but then adds the padding back in on narrow/tall grids.